# Transperency to navbar inverse

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have navbar-inverse, I need to have mild transperency to show my navbar lies over my background image. I applied opacity ,for my navbar but I couldnt achieve the mild transperency.As I expect in image attached here.

[image]

```
.logotitle {
    width:30px;
}


.mynavStyle{
    height: 60px;!important   
}

.navbar {
background:grey;!important
opacity: 0.6;!important
    filter:alpha (opacity=10);!important
}

.coverphoto{
    background-image: url("cphoto.jpg");
    height: 369px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="coverphoto">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse mynavStyle">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img class="logotitle pull-left" src="css/images/logo.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Find Talent</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#">Find Job</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Find Hirer</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Find Talent/Casting Manager</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try, this

```
.navbar {
       background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.6)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply set rgba background:

```
.navbar {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.navbar {
    background-color: transparent;
    background: transparent;
    opacity: 0.6;!important
    filter:alpha (opacity=10);!important
```

}

try this

Answer (score 1):

You should use the background transparency instead opacity, i.e."

```
.navbar{
   background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
```

> **rgba()** affects a single property, like color, background-color or
>   border-color, of a elements targeted by CSS and only of these elements
>
> **opacity** affects all properties (the whole outlook) of targeted
>   elements along with all their DOM tree children

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect syntax:

```
.navbar {
    background:grey;!important
    opacity: 0.6;!important
    filter:alpha (opacity=10);!important
}
```

It should be:

```
.navbar {
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
}
```